# MySQL: SELECT rows containing MAX of a field between rows with overlapping times

Tags: mysql, sql

timespans:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------------+
| ID  | start | stop  |   value     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1  |  1:00 |  3:00 |     6       |
|  2  |  5:00 |  9:00 |     3       |
|  3  |  6:00 | 10:00 |     1       |
+-----+-------+-------+-------------+
```

this is my desired output:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------------+
| ID  | start | stop  |   value     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1  |  1:00 |  3:00 |     6       |
|  2  |  5:00 |  9:00 |     3       |
+-----+-------+-------+-------------+
```

In the case where the start and stop timestamps overlap (as seen in rows 2 & 3), I want the row that contains the `MAX()` of `value` between the two.

If it helps to clarify, here is an approach one could take to solve this programatically:

```
sort(timespans) // by 'value', highest first

results = []
for (t in timespans)
    for (row in results)

        overlap =
                (row.start < t.start && t.start < row.stop) // t.start within row
             || (row.start < t.stop && t.stop < row.stop)   // t.stop within row
             || (t.start < row.start && row.stop < t.stop)  // t encapsulates row

        if (!overlap)
            results.push(t)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this data set is properly representative of the problem. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What if there are two rows with overlapping time periods that have the same `value`?

Comment: `value` is actually the insert timestamp in my real problem. This should never happen.

Comment: and @Strawberry this is an extremely simplified version of my actual problem, in other words an MCVE, so I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: It's oversimplified. What if there are consecutive overlaps? And the linked answer is fairly thorough, so backatcha.

Comment: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and endsafter Event B starts.

Comment: I added some additional detail to try to explain what I am after (though it seems Ike knew what I meant). Not trying to start anything, but linking an answer explaining that it is important to simplify is not a clear way to say I have oversimplified. Why not just request I address any ambiguity up front?

Comment: The concern is that your example might not be "complete". So while my answer provides a query that produces your desired output from your sample input, it may not work on your actual data set, so you'll need to tweak it to get it to handle the complete problem.

Comment: I understand the concern. And I think the programmatic method I added for accomplishing the task adds clarity to my admittedly sparse example data set. That said, a starting point is really all I was after and you provided an excellent one. I just think asking for clarity is more useful than some meta post on how it is important to provide a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to check if there is another row with overlapping `start`/`stop` values and a higher `value` value.

Something like this:

```
select t1.id, t1.start, t1.stop, t1.value 
from your_table t1
where not exists (
  select NULL 
  from your_table t2 
  where ((t2.start between t1.start and t1.stop) or (t2.stop between t1.start and t1.stop))
  and t2.value > t1.value
)
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can tell from the limited information here i would probably use an IF() statement to look for any overlaps and merge the records into one,
so call the sql SELECT * from table_Name and save it to an assoc
then run a loop on the records looking if time_a < time_b
so time_a is = to stop in record 1 time_b is = to start record 2.
 maybe not an IF() maybe a for loop then in the braces copy the information from record 1 and record 2 and make one record where the start is from record 1 and stop is from record 2 delete the 2 records from your assoc and replace with the shiny new record then use the sql INSERT INTO to override the whole table,

I think that is what you want to do if i have miss understood what your trying to achieve i apologize.